# Why progress html element not showing on email (gmail or hotmail), is there any way to show it, and why Nunito google font does not work on emails?

Tags: html, css, email

I tried using  element and using Nunito font with the external link but does not work on emails

```
<progress value="10" max="100">10%</progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Nunito:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" />

/* This text is in Nunito */
.class { 
  font-family: Nunito; 
}
```

You could try out this one for your progress bar:

```
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#f83f83" style="width:50%; background-color:#f83f83; float:left; height:15px;"></td>
  <td bgcolor="#cccccc" style="width:50%; background-color:#cccccc; float:left; height:15px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```